# Transaction fails with ASDServerErrorDomain Code=3504 in production

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

Suddenly in-app purchases of already productive IAPs are failing in the production with the error code:

```
NSUnderlyingError=0x283b42e20 {Error Domain=ASDServerErrorDomain Code=3504 "找不到此项目。" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=找不到此项目。}}}
```

**Environment:** Production

**OS Version：** iOS 15.6.1

What does Code 3504 represent?

Where can I find documentation related to error codes?

I confirm that there have been no prohibited sales areas for the product.

This issue was not found in the sandbox environment.